# Call ruby script from another user not using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

When I need to run a script from my linux user "user1", I do the following commands (right after login with "user1"):

```
rvm use 1.9.3
cd /var/proj
ruby main.rb
```

When developing this script, I have created a bundle with `bundle install`, reading my Gemfile (containing httparty and other stuff).

This is working fine (no reason it would not work :) )

When I log with another user "user2", I'd like to execute the script but cannot have it working:

```
cd /var/proj
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby main.rb
```

The error I get:

```
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)
from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from main.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

It seems it cannot see the bundle created by the other user. Any idea of what needs to be changed ?

I'd like to run this script within supervisor but this is the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the problem, but try a `source /home/user1/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and `rvm use 1.9.3` before executing the script as user2. If that worked, a rvm wrapper might help.

Comment: The point of `rvm` is to give users the ability to control and install their own gemsets. Obviously if you log in as another user you can't just run someone else's ruby and expect their gemsets to magically appear. IMO you should install RVM for the user under which you wish to run the script: that's the point of it.

Comment: However, rvm support a "Multi-User installations", search for it on https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: The thing is I wanted to run this script from supervisor which is ran by root. I did not want to install rvm or any other stuff in the root account. Maybe I should find another supervisor module I could directly ran from the user1 account.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the recommended but you can use RVM from other a/c . Just set the `rvm` required path in another user a/c.

Details instruction:

First go to `user1` and follow this steps

```
  rvm use 1.9.3
  echo $PATH
```

now copy the path which include `rvm` word , in my case it is

```
/home/paritosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/paritosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/paritosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/paritosh/.rvm/bin
```

now go to another `user2` a/c and use `PATH=copied_path:$PATH` so in my case it is

```
PATH=/home/paritosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/paritosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/paritosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/paritosh/.rvm/bin:$PATH
```

Now go to

```
 cd /var/proj 
 ruby main.rb
```

btw, if you want to make the path permanent put the `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` of `user2` a/c .